# condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string[]' and 'string' have no

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was trying to create a condition on the template based on the array value of transactionType but I am receiving an error which is condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string[]' and 'string' have no  ....

Any idea? Thanks.

#html code

```
<div class="report-select-container" *ngIf="reportFilter?.transactionType !== 'Disposition'">
</div>
```

#ts data - reportFilter object

```
    {
       "transactionType":[
          "Disposition"
       ],
       "transactionSubType":null,
       "wagRegion":[
          
       ],
       "repm":[
          
       ],
       "masterBrokerName":[
          
       ],
       "masterBrokerCompany":[
          
       ],
       "phase":[
          
       ]
}
```

Comment: You are comparing an Array of strings with an array, which can never be true. `reportFilter?.transactionType[0] !== 'Disposition'` probably works.

Comment: As you've shown `transactionType` has an array. You're comparing that array against a string. That's not going to work for the reason TS gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, array will never be equal to string.

Use `reportFilter?.transactionType[0] !== 'Disposition'` or `!reportFilter?.transactionType.includes('Disposition')`